iterms2 sourcing bash even if zsh is default
I looks like my iterms terminal is sourcing bash before using zsh and it is doing it multiple times. I can't figure out why.
On the left is the startup from my mac terminal and on the right from items

I have 1 profile on items that runs zsh

Does anyone know why this could happen?
Here is my system info:
macos: 14.6.1
iterms: 3.5.4
zsh: 5.9
omz: master (c68ff8ae)

iTerm doesn't source anything.  It is a terminal emulator, not a shell.  The shell you run inside it sources shell rc files.  Terminal.app runs the shell as a login shell by default, iTerm may not be (especially as for some reason you are explicitly specifying what to run), so look at your combination of shell rc files.

I see several prompts in the iterm screenshot. Did you enter something manually there?

What is your default shell?

@mmmmmm the default is zsh

@nohillside No I don't. That's part of the problem I want to solve.

@bmike The bash_profile is only mentioned in _omz_diag_dump_one_big_text() and it's the same code as in line 230 diagnostics.zsh

@Marc Wilson I get your point. My reason for asking this way was this.
Shouldn't I get the same behavior in both terminals run the same shell rc files?

@Rsale depends on your startup files, mine test for the terminal type and do behave differently. basically for shell startup files read every line and if you don't understand what it does comment it out.

@RSale Again, the terminal doesn’t execute the rc files, the shell does.  zsh reads different files depending on whether or not it is invoked as a login shell.  Which of the many zsh rc files are you actually populating?

What is your login shell shell - see System Settings - Users & Groups and right click on your user name

I would disable iTerm’s  “run this command at start” and see the default shell work all by its normal startup.
For us to look over all your OMZ files might be challenging. Is there any reason you don’t uninstall that and test?
Since Apple’s app works, I’m inclined to focus on iterm2 and OMZ as the culprit.
Does the sourcing of bash line in your image show up in the debug log for initialization for either terminal app?
zsh -xvic exit &> ~/omz-debug.$$.log
